# How to use cakephp classes like cakelog in external script

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a php script in `webroot` folder and i want to use `CakeLog::write` inside it.

Is there anyway to include `cakephp classes` in this kind of scripts?

I know that i can bring my script to some controller action but I want to know is there anyway to use cakephp classes outside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a month it seems that there is no answer for this question.
for solving my problem I wrote my own `CakeLog` class with `write` method:

my `CakeLog` config in `bootstrap.php`:

```
CakeLog::config("default", array(
    'engine' => 'Syslog',
    'prefix' => 'tgui',
    'flag' => LOG_ODELAY | LOG_PID,
    'facility' => LOG_LOCAL0
));
```

so my custom class will be following:

```
class CakeLog {
    public static function write($type, $msg) {
        openlog("tgui", LOG_ODELAY | LOG_PID, LOG_LOCAL0);
        syslog($type, $msg);
        closelog();
   }
}
```